# Display ImageView in SurfaceView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, surfaceview

I am currently attempting to animate some images in my SurfaceView. Right now, I am displaying my images as Bitmaps. However, I think it might be better to implement these Bitmaps as ImageViews. I have not been able to create multiple ImageViews on my SurfaceView (I am trying to not do this in XML, as I want to get things working first and then later change things around so it is more portable). Is there a tutorial somewhere on how to do this, or am I like wayyy off and should just stick to Bitmaps??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally shouldn't try to mix `View` objects and `SurfaceView`. `SurfaceView` is a very special view that provides direct drawing by essentially punching a hole in the current window. It seems better to stick to bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would love to stick with Bitmaps. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to extend the Bitmap class - I'm pretty sure its locked down, right? I want to create an Object which will be a Bitmap, and it has certain attributes. Is there a way to extend this class?

Comment: What about using composition instead of inheritance? In other words, your class will contain a Bitmap as an instance variable and have other data as instance variables as well.